# Put different SQL results in different text areas

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a query in an Oracle Apex system that gets a model number from the serial number, but sometimes it gives me 2 results, for example `MBD213210206` and `MCD213211102`. How can I make the first result show it in the text field `:R1` and the second result in the text field `:R2`.

The query is as follows: `SELECT distinct modnumber FROM tracedata WHERE serialno = :serial;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(modnumber), NULLIF(MAX(modnumber), MIN(modnumber))
FROM tracedata
WHERE serialno = :serial;
```

If you want to select these into variables in PL/SQL:

```
SELECT MIN(modnumber), NULLIF(MAX(modnumber), MIN(modnumber))
INTO r1, r2
FROM tracedata
WHERE serialno = :serial;
```